# How to use jQuery in the latest NextJS version

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

Is there any way to use jQuery (from the CDN or a hosted file) in a NextJS project. NextJS uses JSX and React Components, so traditional `<script>` tags do not work and defining a function use jQuery does not work either. Help appreciated!

Comment: You might ask yourself why you'd do that. jQuery is quickly becoming obsolete in favor of modern JS methods.

Comment: @isherwood actually I wrote this question when I was trying to move from traditional html/css/js to nextjs--in a short amount time I learned how to be a much, much better dev :).